# Are some usages of const only really useful when returning or passing things by reference? Or do they have subtle uses I'm not seeing

Tags: c++, constants

I've read about the various places to put `const`. Some usages seem clearly useful to me. Others however evade me. It would be really helpful if someone could confirm or correct my understanding as I explain my mental model of things.

1. These are the same. I'm not sure I understand why this would ever be useful, though. Does it perhaps allow one to initialize `const int` variables with a function, which in turn allows some compiler optimizations?

   ```
    const int foo();
    int const foo();
   ```
2. These are the same. The returned pointer cannot be used (via dereferencing) to change the values pointed to.

   ```
    const int * foo();
    int const * foo();
   ```
3. This means the returned pointer itself cannot be changed. But, why would it matter if the caller essentially decides to ignore the returned pointer and set it to something else? Is this only really useful if the pointer is returned by reference?

   ```
    int * const foo();
   ```
4. These are the same. It means you can only pass in `const int`s, which allows the compiler to optimize things.

   ```
    int foo(const int foo);
    int foo(int const foo);
   ```
5. This means the passed-in pointer cannot be changed. I'm wondering here too, why would it matter unless the pointer is being passed in by reference?

   ```
    int foo(int * const foo);
   ```
6. This (as a member function) guarantees that the function won't change the state of the object. Also, if the object itself is declared const, then it will only be able to call such functions.

   ```
    int foo(int foo) const;
   ```

Comment: Additionally, `int foo(const int foo);` is the same as `int foo(int);`

Comment: 4 doesn't means "you can only pass in const ints", of course normal `int`s works, too. (and it make no difference as @aschepler said)

Comment: and 5 is basically 4. (since `int*` is a value(type) ), and 3 is 1

Comment: You can also declare member functions `const`, which allows you to call them through a `const` reference or pointer.

Answer (score 3):

1. `const int` as return type is pointless, because in an expression the type of a non-class prvalue result of a function call will be stripped of its top-level `const` anyway. There is no distinction between a `const` and non-`const` prvalue of a non-class type. So the type of `foo()` is just `int`, no matter whether it is declared to return `const int` or `int`.

   It would be different if the return type was a `const` qualified *class type*, e.g. `const std::string foo()`. In that case the `const` would disallow calling non-`const`-qualified member functions directly on the result of `foo()`, e.g. `foo().resize(42)`. Still, this is a very rarely used distinction. And as noted in the comments, under certain conditions it can prevent move operations. E.g. in the above if we have a `std::vector<std::string> v;`, then `v.push_back(foo())` will cause a *copy*, rather than a *move*, of the returned string into the vector.

   However, the `const` qualifier is part of the return type in the function type and therefore it is technically possible to differentiate a function declared with `const` return type from one without it. The type of `int foo(int foo)` is `int(int)`, but the type of `const int foo(int foo)` is `const int(int)`. (However overloading based on return type is not possible for non-template functions anyway. The return type is not part of the function signature.)
2. correct
3. Same as 1. The type of `foo()` is simply `int*`.
4. The top-level `const` in the function parameter does not affect the type or signature of the function (in contrast to 1. where it *does* affect the type). So `int foo(const int foo);` and `int foo(int foo);` declare the same function and both have type `int(int)`. Top-level `const` also doesn't affect how a variable can be initialized, so it doesn't make sense to say "*you can only pass in `const int`*". There are no `const`-qualified prvalues of type `int` anyway and if `int foo` can be initialized from some expression, then so can `const int foo`. The `const` has no implication on initialization or overload resolution. However `const` can be used like this in a function definition to tell the compiler and yourself that this parameter is not intended to be modified in the definition.
5. Same as 4.
6. This is the correct idea, although in the details it is not strictly true. Rather the `const` is only relevant to overload resolution (behaving as if the implicit object parameter was a `const` reference) and the type of `this` (which will be a pointer to `const`). It is still possible to mutate members declared as `mutable` or to use `const_cast` to mutate members. It is also not relevant whether the object itself is `const`, only whether the glvalue through which the member function is called is.

Comment: It should be noted that (1) doesn't apply to classes. For them `const` is harmful, since it inhibits moving.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Both fixed I hope.

Comment: The discussion of return type `const std::string` fits #1 better than #3. A const return type is pointless, but there are technical differences between `int f();` and `const int f();`, unlike the identical `void g(int);` and `void g(const int);`: the function types for `f` are different, which can matter if you use a pointer or reference to the function, and typing both versions in a program is an ill-formed overload, not a redeclaration of the same function.

Comment: (Nothing in your answer is incorrect, that's just additional comments.)

Comment: It should be noted that the specification of a type is a part of the grammar that is reused at many different places (return types, function arguments, variable declarations, ...) and for far more complex types than `int`. Not everything you can specify is meaningful at every place you can specify a type and many combinations aren't overly meaningful, like `const unsigned const unsigned int foo()`. It would just be far more work to specify the exact syntax of what is meaningful for every situation and instead the compiler just ignores the non-sensical and has just one grammar rule for a type.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't think that is a good example. In C++ both duplicate `unsigned` and duplicate `const` is not allowed and in C if I remember correctly only duplicate `const` is allowed. (No idea how the difference between C and C++ came about.) But I agree with your point.

Comment: @user17732522 Ups, you are right. C++ doesn't allow any duplicates. Too late to edit my comment though but I hope my point stands.